# No Implementation for the org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.spi.ProcessEngineProvider spi found on classpath

Tags: camunda, camunda-plugin

I have implemented a sample Camunda Springboot application. It works fine with Internet connection. But when deployed into VDI without internet, The application is not coming up. It shows the error while startup as below

"No Implementation for the org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.api.ProcessEngineProvider spi found on classpath"

Camunda-Springboot and BOM version-7.17.0
Springboot version-2.6.7

I have tried to implement the interface and creating service for Java service loader. Still no luck.

Comment: Camunda works without changes without Internet. You don´t need to implement the interface. How are you building the application? try if a build from start.camunda.com works. I consider it most likely that some mistake happened and that the two tests are not using the same build. The later attempt may be missing a jar or a clean apckaghe is needed.